# Flex/Flash - Include assets for iOS

Tags: ios, flash, ipad, apache-flex, assets

So, finally got the retina resolution to work with flashbuilder/flex and windows when exporting to iPad, but now I need some more help.

I want to port our old porfolio to iOS, so we can have it with us when we are meeting up with new clients.

EDIT: Ok, local storage seems like a lot of work, so I'll include it all in one huge .ipa file..

Now, our porfolio contains a lot of videos. What codec should this be to be playable in our flash application on the iPad?

Comment: You are actually asking multiple questions in one go here, try to split up your questions and be more specific. Basically if all you need the app for is for demo purposes, you can easily include all video and other assets into your .ipa. Otherwise you will have to write a remote service to fetch all your data (video,..) from as well since you will not have access to the IOS filesystem from within AIR.

Comment: So there is no way for me to upload the assets through itunes after installing my app? Like in Azul video player, where you can upload your videos directly to your app through itunes.. These assets will be many GB..

Comment: Azul video is probably a Native app with access to the ios Filesystem.
To achieve this through AIR, you will have a lot to work around, a native extension might do the trick. Not even sure if it is possible at all though.

Comment: Ahh, ok. And here I was hoping for a simple solution, like a command to enable local storeage access through itunes :P

Comment: Updated my question. Take a look if you have any info =)